# How to show date from firestore (timestamp) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting timestamp from firestore. How to show it in Date/month/year in flutter?
Tried so many ways but it shows error: String is subtype of Timestamp or datetime.
Below is my code.

```
   itemCount: orderList.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            final cartOrder = orderList.data.docs[index]['cartorder'];
            final Timestamp orderedDate =
                orderList.data.docs[index]['ordered_date'];
            final delivered = orderList.data.docs[index]['delivered'];
            String myDate =
                DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm').format(orderedDate.toDate());
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a timestamp. Use DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch

```dart
DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
String myDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm').format(date);
```